# Раскладка клавиатуры

Tags: настройки, ubuntu, linux

Здравствуйте! У меня Ubuntu 11.10, помогите мне поменять раскладку клавиатуры, допустим c русской на английскую <kbd>shift+ctrl</kbd> ?

Answer (score 2):

Если во время установки, вы самостоятельно не меняли способ переключения раскладки, то это сочетание клавиш <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. Кроме того раскладка меняется мышью: в панели состояния есть соответствующая иконка (клавиатура и сокращение en/ru), там же есть и настройки выбора горячей клавиши для переключения раскладок.

Comment: Я не могу найти, подскажите.

Comment: Там нет смены клавиатуры, как найти?

Comment: Нашел, все спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Узнать раскладку клавиатуры можно ещё через конфигурационный файл **keyboard**,который расположен в `/etc/default/`.

Открываем файл правами root текстовым редактором вбив в терминале команду:

`sudo gedit /etc/default/keyboard`

Внутренности файла будут выглядеть примерно так:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us,ru"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Где в `XKBLAYOUT` написаны языки на которые вы переключаетесь,а в `XKBOPTIONS` alt_shift это связка клавиш с помощью которой вы переключаетесь по этим языкам.